# Facebook sharer 403 forbidden

Tags: facebook, joomla, http-status-code-403, mod-security2

I have a website in Joomla hosted on my own vps. I have installed plugin for meta og, but share on facebook still give an 403 error. I've checked the facebook debugger, and it's like it can not resolve the url (bad http response). 
Other tools  for social analysis of the page show me the page and the meta correctly, and other social sharer like **google+**  work good. Only facebook sharer is broken.

I have tried with gzip on and off, but still **403 forbidden.**
Someone know how can i make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go check if you have any other plugins installed, that try to block requests by what they think are “bad bots.”

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this: there was a mod_security rule (protocol violations) that was blocking the sharer of Facebook. If I remove that rule, facebook sharing is ok.

So, I am not an expert of mod_security, but I don't think it's good thing to remove completely a security rule.. Do you know if it is possible to write a specific exception?

Comment: Yes. Would need details of the rule firing and the audit log message.